# Angular CKEditor Image Upload

Tags: angular, ckeditor, image-upload

Hello In angular app I am using CKEditor. For image upload I use code below

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckeditor-htqrui)

```
 export class UploadAdapter {
    private loader;
    constructor(loader: any) {
      this.loader = loader;
    }
  
    public upload(): Promise<any> {
      return this.readThis(this.loader.file);
    }
  
    readThis(file: any): Promise<any> {
      console.log(file)
      let imagePromise: Promise<any> = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
        myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
          console.log("girdi");
          let image = myReader.result;
          console.log(image);
          resolve({ default: "data:image/png;base64," + image });
        }
        myReader.readAsDataURL(file);
      });
      return imagePromise;
    }
  
  }
```

in component

```
 onReady(eventData) {
    eventData.plugins.get('FileRepository').createUploadAdapter = function (loader) {
      console.log(btoa(loader.file));
      return new UploadAdapter(loader);
    };
  }
```

in html

```
<ckeditor [editor]="Editor"(ready)="onReady($event)" data="<p>Hello, world!</p>"></ckeditor>
```

I take error below

> **TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader':
> parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.**

Where is my missing ?

Thanks in advance

**Thanks to @Chellappan வ for his suggestion. It solved error. But Image is **disappear after a second ago.****

Comment: Can you share UploadAdapter class code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file : Promise.<(File | null)>
```

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_upload_filerepository-FileLoader.html) file return type is Promise so we have resolve before assigning the file to readAsDataURL.

**Try this:**

```
 public async upload(): Promise<any> {
      const file = await this.loader.file;
      return this.readThis(file);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks it solves error but. Image is disappear after a second. That is demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ckeditor-htqrui

Comment: myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
          let image = myReader.result;
                 resolve({ default: image});
        } inside resolve we have to set default property pointing image some think like this.